# cmake cross-compiling arm transitional dependencies libs not found

Tags: cmake

I have a big program in C++ that i cross-compile for a Jetson TX2
This program is structured like this :

```
root  
| - module1  
| | - CMakeLists.txt  
| - module2  
| | - CMakeLists.txt  
| - CMakeLists.txt  
| - toolchain.cmake
```

Each module sub-folder create a shared library that my main target links.
The toolchain for the jetson is

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

SET(CROSS_COMPILE "jetson")

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-5)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-5)

SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /usr/local/sysroot_jetson)

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_DIR} "")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

I had no problem at all so far until now that i need to include a new module that has tensorflow has its dependency.

I have installed tensorflow_cc libs in /usr/local/lib.
This TF libs is compiled with GPU support and therefore links many things from the cuda-9.0 that is installed on the jetson.

The CMakeLists.txt of the module simply link to tensorflow as follow.
This is simplified of course.

```
target_link_libraries(${LIB_NAME} -ltensorflow_cc)
```

As long as i don't cross-compile it works just fine.
Compiling directly on the jetson or my host machine works fine.

But adding the toolchain just go nowhere.
When compiling, the shared lib for the tensorflow module actually compile fine but linking the final target just output the following

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libcublas.so.9.0, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libcusolver.so.9.0, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libcudart.so.9.0, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libcuda.so.1, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib//libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libcufft.so.9.0, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib//libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libcurand.so.9.0, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib//libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib//libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDrotm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
/usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so: undefined reference to `cusolverDnZgeqrf@libcusolver.so.9.0'
/usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/lib//libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cuEventElapsedTime'
......
```

All the required files can be found in the sysroot at /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/local/cuda/lib64

My understanding is that all ld extra path that are set in /etc/ld.so.conf.d are not used or read.
I should be able to instruct cmake to look for those extra search path but i tried everything i could read without any change.
pkg-config has files for all the cuda libs, so i can do

```
pkg_check_modules(cudaall REQUIRED cuda-9.0 cublas-9.0 cusolver-9.0 cudart-9.0 cufft-9.0 curand-9.0)
```

It found them but it just fails with

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcusolver
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcufft
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
```

Adding a -L${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64 (which i should not to) just spiral to other nvidia libs not being found.

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libnvrm_gpu.so, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libnvrm.so, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.28.2.1, needed by /usr/local/sysroot_jetson/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

What i really don't understand is, why cmake care about which libs tensorflow_cc.so links?
Should not that be a runtime problem?
Can't i just link to tensorflow_cc.so with caring about it's dependencies at compile time?

This is all very confusing to me.

Any insight would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: "why cmake care about which libs tensorflow_cc.so links?" - CMake cares nothing. Look, the warnings are from the **linker** (`.../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld`), not from CMake. When link with shared libraries, the linker links also with all libraries they depends. So it needs to find those dependent libraries. And you RPATH settings doesn't allow the linker to find those libraries. Note, that warning message doesn't list `-L` option as a solution for a problem.

Comment: Ok make sense but how do i instruct additional path for the linker in a cross-compiling environment to do the same job as what is found in /etc/ld.so.conf.d ?

Answer (score 0):

in CMakeLists.txt add:

`set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT} $ENV{LDFLAGS}")`

in console run:

`export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath=/sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu  "$LDFLAGS`

after build your app